# PHP Loop Question

Tags: php

echo "";
    while (list ($key, $val) = each ($users)) {
    echo "$val\n\n";
    }
    echo "";
    while (list ($key2, $val2) = each ($enable)) {
    echo "$val2\n\n";
    } 
    echo "";

I want to format this into table with side by side where should be

```
$val $val2
```

Currently its in

```
$val
$val2
```

What should i amend to achieve this?

Thank you for your kind assistance.

Comment: Do you want all the users on one row and then all the enable on the next row?  Or  User / Enable on one row and then User / Enable on the next row?

Comment: My question to you is why would you have two separate arrays for `$users` and `$enable`?  It seems as though you should just have a multi-dimensional array with the user and whether or not they are enabled...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see what you're trying to do now.  Something to this effect?:

```
echo "<table>";
while (list ($key, $val) = each ($users)) {
list ($key2, $val2) = each ($enable);
echo "<tr><td>$val</td>";
echo "<td>$val2</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: This is a little safer:
echo "<table>";
while (list ($key, $val) = each ($users)) {
echo "<tr><td>$val</td>";
if (list ($key2, $val2) = each ($enable))
echo "<td>$val2</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

Answer (score 1):

Just make one `while()` loop and echo the `<tr><td>val</td><td>val2</td></tr>` part

Answer (score 1):

You need to do some trickery to loop through both arrays at the same time since they need to be on the same row:

```
echo '<table>';
$user_count = count($users);
$enable_count = count($enable);
$max = max($user_count, $enable_count );
for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i ++) {
    $val = '&nbsp;';
    $val2 = '&nbsp;';
    if ($i < $user_count) $val = $users[$i];
    if ($i < $enable_count) $val2 = $enable[$enable];
    echo "<tr><td>$val</td><td>$val2</td></tr>";
}
echo '</table>';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the format user/ enable on one line and then user/enable on the next line, you'll need to do some array work first so you can get them in the same loop.

```
echo "<table>";
foreach(array_combine($users, $enable) as $u => $e){
   echo "<tr><td>$u</td><td>$e</td></tr>\n\n";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can condense this into a single loop for optimal performance assuming your keys are integers starting at 0:

```
$len = min(count($users), count($enable));
if ($len > 0) {
    echo '<table>';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i) {
        echo '<tr><td>' . $users[$i] . '</td><td>' . $enable[$i] . '</td></tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

Comment: this will not work except that the $users and $enable has the same index or keys which usualy arent, have a look at my for loop ist that cool?

Answer (score 0):

hmm you could do that in a for loop this is smart and is readable

```
echo "<table><tr>";
for($u=0;$e=0;$u<count($users),$e<count($enable);$i++,$u++)
{
echo "<td>$users[$u]['idntknowthekeysethere']</td></tr>\n\n";
echo "<td>$enable[$e]['idntknowthekeysethere']</td></tr>\n\n";
}

echo "</tr></table>";
```